# Why does outputting a vector's size cause allocations?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Take the following program:

```
const std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{10, std::vector<int>(10)};
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
```

By itself, only 12 allocations are made. If I add a loop:

```
for (auto e : v)
    std::cout << e.size() << " ";
```

22 allocations are made. Aren't the allocations made in advance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you make a copy of a vector in each iteration. Try

```
for (const auto& e : v) // take a reference each iteration
    std::cout << e.size() << " ";
```

and see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

`for (auto e : v)` creates a copy of each container element causing allocations.

The reason for this is that `auto` resolves to `std::vector<int>`, that is `e` is taken by value.

To get rid of extra allocations use `for (auto& e : v)` or `for (auto&& e : v)`.

You can also write `for (const auto& e : v)`, but `const` here is redundant because `v` is constant.

Answer (score 3):

with `for (auto e : v)`, you make copy.

use `for (const auto& e : v)` instead.

Comment: What is the e : v syntax called, so I can read about it, this seems interesting.

Comment: @user3 range based for

Comment: @user3670482: look at *C++11 range-based for loops*